# CSRF and a cookie-to-form approach

Tags: forms, security, cookies, csrf, csrf-protection

A common pattern for protecting against CSRF is to have the server generate a hidden input in forms with a random token. The server then expects to see this token upon form submissions.

Another common pattern is the [cookie-to-header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery#Cookie-to-Header_Token) pattern. In this case, the token is put in a cookie (without `HttpOnly`), and that token is expected from future requests in *both* the cookie and a header. Javascript on the page is expected to handle this. One advantage of this method is that the server doesn't have to keep state. Another is that GETs are also secured (even though, of course, GETs should anyhow not alter state).

Usually you pick one or the other depending on whether your site is an SPA or not. But why not just *always* send the token in the cookie, and expect it back *either* in a header and in the cookie, *or* in the form and in the cookie? The former case would work exactly as the cookie-to-header method above, and the latter would expect forms to be populated with hidden fields *in the client* (i.e, by javascript). All you need for the latter is a little snippet of JS that runs on document ready. This is much easier for people writing frameworks because there's only one system to implement (and no state); it's much easier for people using the web framework because they don't have to remember to add hidden fields to every form. And it seems safer, since GETs are taken care of.

Are there any downsides (besides *requiring* that the client run javascript)? I don't think I've seen this idea implemented or discussed anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

First, you would very rarely want to protect GET requests from CSRF, because as you correctly noted, GETs should not alter state, and as such should be harmless. A CSRF attack on a GET request could be pulled out by a simple link, that's a very special case if you need some kind of a protection against that (but it may still be possible for some requests).

Apart from that, you can mix good solutions, the risk of that is increasing your attack surface and also increasing complexity - risks that you may or may not be willing to accept.

You have to be careful what parameters you compare with each other and what you base your security on. The security of a token generated and remembered by the server and written into forms is based on server-side session security, the fact that a user can't directly read other users' session contents. This is a fairly solid assumption. Security of the cookie-to-header method is based on the fact that a browser will not allow an attacker's website to read cookies set for the application domain - this is much weaker, an arbitrary browser may have bugs, it may have malicious plugins/extensions installed, etc. It can still be accepted, but the risk profile is different. *Implementing both solutions means taking the risks from both.*

Also in case of mixed solutions, there is the risk of comparing the wrong things due to implementation errors (increased complexity). For example comparing a cookie value to a value stored in the server side session would obviously negate the effect, cookies would be sent with requests from an attacker's site too.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd call it a mixed solution. If anything, it's *less* mixed than what people usually do, which is have one thing for forms, and another thing altogether for XHR, leaving an attacker to pick between them.

Comment: That's a fair point, but I'd say risks are different for the different implementations, but not mixed in the sense that only one set of risks apply to any given query. You're right though that in the long run (and especially in a larger organization with many developers for example) it may be beneficial to have one verified solution instead of letting developers choose or implement something custom.